# Wireless Device for TV

Tags: tv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to stream video from my computer to my TV? (preferably wirelessly)](https://superuser.com/questions/9120/whats-the-best-way-to-stream-video-from-my-computer-to-my-tv-preferably-wirele)

I want to be able browse my PC through my TV via a wireless connection. The TV does not have any wireless capabilities. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are various adapters available to connect over wireless to your TV's VGA Port.

For Eg.

[http://www.amazon.com/Aitech-Pro-Wireless-Converter-06-078-001-08/dp/B000BD68KM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BD68KM)